# SQL for Moving Average with variable weights

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as below

```
Day_No  Average  Count
------ -------- ------
1       7.5      12
2       12       15
3       15       4
4       13       14
5       6.5      12
6       21       17
7       15       4
8       11       15
9       15       11
10      10       13
11      9        40
12      13       12
.
.
.
.
.
```

I want to generate a 7 day moving average. I have seen solutions where each day has an equal weight but clearly each average needs to be weighted based on count. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you expect for output? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Day_No,Run_avg [1,x1] [2,x2] where x1 would be sum of the next 7 counts x averages / number of counts and x2 would be the same shifted by one.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve. Maybe this does what you want:

```
select day_no,
       average,
       cnt,
       avg(average * cnt) over (order by day_no rows between 7 preceding and current row) as running_avg
from data
order by day_no;
```

The `rows between 7 preceding and current row` clause assumes that there is one row for each day in the result.

(Note that I used `cnt` for the `count` column as it is not a good idea to use a reserved word as a column name).

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa0a84/1

Comment: This is nearly there but somehow one needs to divide by the counts, you can see that the running average is clearly too big.

Comment: @TonyWolff, perhaps you want this, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa0a84/8. It would be better if you show some sample output in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Need to sum the product of averages and counts and then divide by counts both over the range.

```
select day_no,
       average,
       cnt,
       sum(average * cnt) over (order by day_no rows between 7 preceding and current row)/sum(cnt) over (order by day_no rows between 7 preceding and current row) as running_avg
from data
order by day_no;
```

Thanks to a horse_with_no_name for putting me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

```
select initial_data.full_sum/initial_data.fullCount as the_avg
from
    (select
      sum(Average * count) as full_sum,
      sum(count) as full_count
    from the_table
    group by <the grouping condition>) initial_data
```

Something like this. Don't remember proper oracle syntax for all the group and arithmetic

Comment: This would compute the average for every group, but not a moving average. I think we have to use analytic functions for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with following query:

```
select Day_No day, 
   (select sum(Average*Count)/sum(Count) 
      from table 
      where Day_No between day-7 and day) 
from table;
```